# modification of bfs for ford fulkerson algorithm,to find augmenting path

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search, ford-fulkerson

i am using bfs to find augmenting path.but it is producing same path every time.but ford fulkerson algorithm requires that,we choose different path every time from source to sink,so can somebody suggest me how to modify bfs so that it produces different path every time between source and sink.graph is directed and weighted

Comment: Each time use a random child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the BFS ignores edges where all of the capacity has been used. Usually, the BFS is being run on the so-called *residual network*, in which each edge capacity tells how much capacity *remains* on that edge (given the flow you've sent through that edge). You can either maintain a separate residual graph, or you can have an implicit one by making the BFS look at the difference between the original capacity and the current flow for each edge (and treating an edge as absent if its capacity is zero).

Comment: but bfs chooses path based on no.vertices,i mean shortest path is based on no. of vertices from source to sink

Comment: i am  changing capacity but  it is not helping

Comment: Yes, so the first time it is run, BFS will choose the shortest path. However, after that path has been found, Ford-Fulkerson will send as much flow as possible down that path; this will use all of the capacity on at least one of the edges, thus "breaking" the path. The next BFS will necessarily find a different path because at least one of the edges on the old path is now unusable. As I said, you need to make sure that edges where all of the capacity is used will be ignored by the BFS.

Comment: can somebody please guide me how to use ford fulkerson algorithm for practical applications like project selection,airline scheduing